# Как настроить дату создания файла?

Tags: php

Использую данный код: `date ("Y-m-d H:i:s.", filemtime($file))`
чтобы выводить дату создания файла, но время отличается на два часа.
Как это поправить?

Comment: Похоже, время выводится по гринвичу или около того. Что-нибудь вроде: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow'); и укажите нужную вам зону.

Comment: date("Y-m-d ").(date("H")+2).date(":i:s")."\r\n"

Comment: @Quazimorda, подскажите, а если пользователь будет не из временной зоны `Europe/Moscow`, ведь дата снова будет некорректно отображаться? Можно ли это сделать чтобы определяло автоматически?

Comment: Одного php тут уже будет недостаточно. Но с javascript и парочкой библиотек (выполняющихся на стороне клиента) это возможно. Был как-то вопрос и ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525617/how-to-detect-users-timezone